# Jquery div fadeIn on load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I just have a Div ".text" that i want to fade in on a subdomain page… I googled on stackoverflow and came up with this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
$('.text').hide().fadeIn('400');

});
</script>
```

The CSS is just font styling… I even tried it before with a `display:none;` and without the `.hide()` but somehow it does not work… I load this jQuery:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Do I need another one? Or do I need to name the subdomain in the script? I wanted to put the script in my index.php file… I just can not explain it to myself…

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: Try to make it reproducible on https://jsfiddle.net so we can be sure it is not only your browser. Using the same code than yours [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8qwh6yx/) is working for me

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xketorjL/

Comment: Could it possibly get problems with other JS Scripts that I use?

Comment: Thank You! Jab, these JFiddles work in my browser too, but on my page it does not… I load the script on www.mydomain.com/index.php … The .text div appears in the site www.mydomain.com/index.php/about/ … could there be a problem?

Comment: The HTML is div="#dapper" –> div="#exhibit" -> div=".text" … is it not possible to get to the ".text" directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the script file next to including the Jquery plugin.

Since there is no fault in your code.

This may be the problem.

Comment: This was it! There was something with my CMS!!! The Library was only loaded on www.mydomain.com/index.php/projects which is marked as my "home" site … on www.mydomain.com/index.php/about it was not loaded somehow…

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are feeding in `fadeIn('400')` 400 is an int value not a string. Try using

```
 fadeIn(1600)
```

and you might see a more noticeable fade effect.

Comment: Jab, this works… but only on the "home" page … You see, it put the script in my "index.php" file … on www.mydomain.com/index.php/projects it works, but on www.mydomain.com/index.php/about it does not! Strange!

Comment: Edit your question with some html where its not working